# Tableau SUMIF statement

Tags: if-statement, sum, tableau-api, sumifs, tableau-desktop

I have a dataset of movies with the amount of views per day, I want to sum total views per movie and I am doing the following:

```
SUM(IF [Title] = [Title]
    THEN [Views]
    END)
```

But is not giving me the right numbers, can anyone please help me?

Comment: the calculated field without additional context seems off... furthermore, please add some sample input and output in order to check the "right" number.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to make a calculated field every time you want to see values in Tableau - that's part of the beauty of it.

Assuming that the Views field is a numeric measure by default, and the Movie field is a text dimension by default, then just drag Movie to one shelf (such as Rows) and Views to another (such as Columns).